# GWT: how to use XFBML "like/send" buttons for dynamic pages

Tags: facebook, gwt, uibinder, xfbml

How can I properly render a facebook Like/Send button pair in a GWT app?

There are a few issues at play here:

1. I'm using UIBinder. The solution to [this
   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806306/how-do-you-let-uibinder-pass-tags-without-binding-them-so-xfbml-works) at least lets me emded
   the tags.
2. The like/send buttons need to be
   added to the DOM dynamically (for
   example, when the user navigates to
   a particular page state in my app).
3. The page being "liked" is actually a
   GWT-style "hash" URL, linking to a
   particular (bookmarkable) state of
   my app.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Like.java](https://github.com/denormans/FacebookGWT/blob/master/api/src/main/java/com/denormans/facebookgwt/api/client/ui/widgets/Like.java) in [FacebookGWT](https://github.com/denormans/FacebookGWT). It demonstrates a widget that creates a fb:like element.  It doesn't support the "send" option yet, but that's easy enough to add.

After you've added the fb:like element to the DOM, you need to parse XFBML again:

```
private native void parseXFBMLJS(final Element element) /*-{
  $wnd.FB.XFBML.parse(element);
}-*/;
```

*Original Answer:*

The easiest way to do this via GWT is to support the use of History in your GWT app.  History works by using hashes (`#`) on the URL.  GWT has built-in support for reading the hashed values via the History class, and listening for History changes.  You can also initiate History changes within your app to other parts of your app.

To be more explicit as to which part of your app is referenced, you can use slashes in the history entry or even parameters (e.g. `#name=value&name2=value2`)

Comment: By the way, if you are using Facebook with GWT, take a look at a library I've been working on: [FacebookGWT](http://denormans.github.com/FacebookGWT/)

Comment: I don't quite follow you here- how does this support the Like/Send button? I've had history enabled in my GWT apps for years, and also make good use of the (relatively recent) "Place" pattern.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on the edits to your question.  Hope this helps.